# django URL logout

Tags: django, url

After clicking logout, the page directs to /logout/addwine/index.html instead of /addwine/index.html.

Is there a way to get around this?

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
   url(r'^login/$', login, kwargs={'template_name':'addwine/login.html'}, name= 'addwine_login'),
   url(r'^logout/$', logout, kwargs={'next_page':'addwine/index.html'}, name= 'addwine_logout'),
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "relative path", just put a "/" before url, to indicate that you want an absolut path, like this:

```
kwargs={'next_page':'/addwine/index.html'}
```

Comment: well, it doesn't work.. i tried '/addwine/index.html' and '/index.html', but it doesnt seem to find the match from URL pattern.. But, it works if i just use the absolute path /website

Comment: you need first, to add "/addwine/index.html" to your URL pattern,  if not, django doesn't know how to handle that request. In your case "/website" works because "/website" is in your URL pattern.

Comment: i do have url(r'^$', 'addwine.views.index', name= 'addwine_index'), in url.py                                                              def index(request):  return render_to_response('addwine/index.html') in views.py

Comment: ah ok, look at your url name, it's 'addwine_index', then you have two options, kwargs={'next_page':'addwine_index'} or kwargs={'next_page':'/addwine/index'}    , last one without ".html"

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. What I did is, where you rendering the logout url in template :

```
<a href="{% url addwine_logout %}?next=/addwine/index.html">Logout</a>
```

Add the next param into it. You can add the next param by passing from the view or through javascript, Whichever way you like.